# Enter your name via a D-pad

Tags: code-golf

## The puzzle:

Consider a console/hand-held game with a d-pad where you are required to enter a name of sorts. This appeared in many older games before the use of QWERTY was popularised in consoles (e.g. I believe the Wii uses a QWERTY keyboard layout for input). Typically, the on-screen keyboard looks to the effect of*:

Default:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A B C D E F G H I J
K L M N O P Q R S T
U V W X Y Z _ + ^ =
```

With the case switched:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a b c d e f g h i j
k l m n o p q r s t
u v w x y z - + ^ =
```

That is, all alphanumeric keys and the following:

`_`: A single space
`-`: A hyphen
`+`: Switch case for the next letter only
`^`: Toggle caps lock (that is, switch the case of all letters)
`=`: Enter, complete

*Obviously I replaced keys like "BKSP" and "ENTER" with shorter versions

And then the hardware would include a d-pad (or some form of control where you could go `up`, `down`, `left` and `right`)

The screen also typically let you move from one side directly to the other. That is, if you were focussed on the letter `J`, pressing `right` would allow you to move to the letter `A`.

Whenever I was entering my name, I'd always try to work out the quickest way to do so.

## Goal:

Your program will take string input which may include any alphanumeric character including a space and hyphen, and your goal is to **output the shortest amount of *key presses*** on the d-pad to output the required string.

## Considerations:

You do not need to include the key pressed for *pressing* the actual character.
Focus always starts at the `A`
Enter `=` must be *pressed* at the end

## Example:

`input: Code Golf`
`output: 43`

**Explained:**
`A` -> `C` = 2
`C` -> `^` = 6 (moving to the left)
`^` -> `o` = 5
`o` -> `d` = 2
`d` -> `e` = 1
`e` -> `+` = 5
`+` -> `_` = 1
`_` -> `+` = 1
`+` -> `G` = 3
`G` -> `o` = 3
`o` -> `l` = 3
`l` -> `f` = 5
`f` -> `=` = 6

Note that it is quicker to hit the `+` twice for a `_` and a `G` than it is to hit `^` once, then swap back.

The winning submission (I'll allow at least 1w) will be the shortest solution (in bytes). As this is my first question, I hope this is clear and not too hard.

Comment: Nice challenge! Just one point, 48 hours is probably too little. That's how long it takes for bounties to be allowed, so it should be more around a week+.

Comment: @Maltysen thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the challenge

Comment: Can you wrap vertically, too, or just horizontally?

Comment: @AlexReinking that's a great point! Yes you can.

Comment: Great! My implementation does that, so I just wanted to double-check.

Comment: For those testing the hyphen: `A-Z` is 11

Comment: Sorry, but why did the bounty go to the Swift submission? Mine was 300 bytes shorter.

Comment: The problem of "finding the shortest path" is a good candidate for being solved with state space search, eg "A Star search" algorithm. Hipster4j is a great Java library for this.

Comment: Does `+` really *switch the case* for the next letter, even if you’re in Caps Lock mode? So I could type “STEvEN” by going “STE+vEN”?

Comment: @Timwi AFAIK that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ruby (369 bytes)

Takes input from command line.

```
K="0123456789"+('A'..'Z').to_a.join+" +^="
Q=K.downcase.sub' ','-'
def d x,y
t,s=(x/10-y/10).abs,(x%10-y%10).abs
[t,4-t].min+[s,10-s].min
end
def v s,i,l,a
return l if s.empty?
c,r=s[0],s[1..-1]
j=K.index(c.upcase)||36
return v(r,j,l+d(i,j),a)if a.include?c
s,p=d(i,37)+d(37,j),d(i,38)+d(38,j)
[v(r,j,l+s,a),v(r,j,l+p,a==K ? Q : K)].min
end
puts v("#{ARGV[0]}=",10,0,K)
```

Saved a bunch of bytes thanks to @Charlie :)

Comment: `j=(K.index(c.upcase) or 36)` can be replaced with `j=K.index(c.upcase)||36` to save 4 bytes.

`def d(x,y)` can replaced with `def d x,y` to save a byte, and same goes for `def v`.

`v(...) if` to `v(...)if` for another byte.

On the last line, `v(...)` can be replaced with `v ...` to save 1 byte, and `true` with `!!0` to save another byte.

Comment: Thanks! I don't really know Ruby. I translated this from python...

Comment: I can also replace `&&` with `&` and `||` with `|`.

Comment: Your first line (`K=...`) can be replaced with a range (`K='0123456789'+('A'..'Z').to_a.join+' +^='`)

Comment: Shaves another 2 off!

Answer (score 9):

## Swift 1.2, <s>812</s> <s>588</s> 670 bytes

Edit: Removed 224 bytes by replacing the large arrays of numbers with a Range and converting it to an Array instead.

Edit2: Added looping vertically

```
typealias S=String
typealias I=Int
var A:(I)->S={S(UnicodeScalar($0))},B:(I)->(I,I)={a in(a%10,a/10)},a=Array(48...57).map{A($0)},b=[a+(Array(65...90)+[32,43,94,61]).map{A($0)},a+(Array(97...122)+[45,43,94,61]).map{A($0)}],z=Process.arguments
z.removeAtIndex(0)
func C(e:I,f:I)->I{let(a,b)=B(e),(c,d)=B(f)
return min(abs(d-b), abs(4-(d-b)))+min(abs(c-a),abs(10-(c-a)))}
func D(c:S,_ e:I=10,_ f:Bool=false,_ g:Bool=false)->I{if count(c)==0{return C(e,39)}
let h=c.startIndex,i=c.endIndex,j=S(c[h])
if let k=find(b[f ?1:0],j){return C(e,k)+D(c[advance(h,1)..<i],k,(g ?(!f):f),false)}else{return min(C(e,37)+D(c,37,!f,true),C(e,38)+D(c,38,!f,false))}}
print(D(" ".join(z)))
```

To run, put the code in a `.swift` file and run it with `swift <filename> <your name>`

---

This uses the simple approach where the two 'keyboards' are stored as arrays.

`B:(I)->(I,I)={a in(a%10,a/10)}`
Converts an index from the array to an x,y position on the virtual keyboard.

`func C(e:I,f:I)->I{let(a,b)=B(e),(c,d)=B(f)
 return abs(d-b)+min(abs(c-a),abs(10-(c-a)))}` Takes a start/end index and returns the minimum number of moves to get from once to the other (accounting for horizontal wrap)

`func D(c:S,_ e:I=10,_ f:Bool=false,_ g:Bool=false)->I` Is the main recursive function that does most of the calculations.  It calculates the distance from the current position to the target character, unless the case should change, then it calculates **both** the *shift* **and** the *caps lock* methods and takes the smallest.

Running `swift codegolf.swift Code Golf` prints `43`

Comment: Needs to account for vertical wrap.

Comment: Updated to account for vertical wrap too.

Answer (score 4):

## Python <s>679</s> <s>661</s> <s>619</s> <s>602</s> <s>589</s> <s>576</s> <s>539</s> <s>520</s> <s>496</s> 482 Bytes

Run this and it will ask for a input (without prompt text). For the input `Code Golf` it prints `43`.

```python
a=input()+'=';b=0;c="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-+^=";d=0;e=[0,1];f='+';g='^';h=[i.isupper()or i==' 'for i in a];i=abs;p=lambda z:all([i==b for i in z]);q=0
def l(z):global s;k=c.index(z.lower().replace(' ','-'));s=[k%10,int(k/10)];m,n=s;return sum([min(i(m-e[0]),i(10-(m-e[0]))),min(i(n-e[1]),i(4-(n-e[1])))])
def o(z):global d,e;d+=l(z);e=s
for r in a:
 if p(h[q:q+3]):o(g);b^=1
 if p(h[q:q+2]):
  if l(f)<l(g):o(f)
  else:o(g);b^=1
 if p([h[q]]):o(f)
 o(r);q+=1
print(d)
```

---

Full program:

```python
input = input() + '='
capsOn = False

keys = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-+^="
totalKeys = 0
caret = [0, 1]

shiftKey = '+'
capsKey = '^'

cases = [char.isupper() or char == ' ' for char in input]

def locate(char):
    """
        Find the location of the char on the keyboard
        regardless of case
    """
    location = keys.find(char.replace(' ', '-').lower())
    return [location % 10, int(location / 10)]


def dist(key):
    """
        Calculate the min dist to a char
    """
    nx, ny = locate(key)
    return sum([min(abs(nx - caret[0]), abs(10 - (nx - caret[0]))), min(abs(ny - caret[1]), abs(4 - (ny - caret[1])))])


def moveTo(char):
    """
        Move the caret to the char, ignoring case and
        adds the dist to the tally
    """
    global totalKeys, caret
    totalKeys = totalKeys + dist(char)

    print(keys[caret[0] + caret[1] * 10], '->', char, '=', dist(char))

    caret = locate(char)

diffCase = lambda case: all([i == capsOn for i in case])

for ind, ch in enumerate(input):
    if diffCase(cases[ind:ind + 3]): # use caps
        moveTo(capsKey)
        capsOn ^= 1
    elif diffCase(cases[ind:ind + 2]): # use closest
        if dist(shiftKey) < dist(capsKey):
            moveTo(shiftKey)
        else:
            moveTo(capsKey)
            capsOn ^= 1
    elif diffCase([cases[ind]]): # use shift
        moveTo(shiftKey)

    moveTo(ch) # apply the move

print('Total:', totalKeys)
```

---

### Extended output from the full program:

```
Code Golf
a -> C = 2
c -> ^ = 6
^ -> o = 5
o -> d = 2
d -> e = 1
e -> + = 5
+ -> _ = 1
- -> + = 1
+ -> G = 3
g -> o = 3
o -> l = 3
l -> f = 5
f -> = = 6
Total: 43
```

---

> Saved a byte thanks to @justin https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18983/42736
> 4 @xnor https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40791/42736
> 19 thanks to @Alex

Comment: Any help is appreciated as I'm still learning python and this is my first code golf.

Comment: You can use a space instead of an underscore in your internal tables.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

## C 675 Bytes

Takes input from command line argument. Uses recursive main:

```
#define Y(_) (!isdigit(_)?!isalpha(_)?3:1+(toupper(_)-65)/10:0)
#define X(_) (!isdigit(_)?!isalpha(_)?_-32&&_-45?_-43?9-(_==94):7:6:(toupper(_)-5)%10:_-48)
x,y,z;char*s;main(a,_,p,q,r){a<2?s[_]?!isdigit(s[_])&&((s[_]-32&&!isupper(s[_]))||!a)&&((s[_]-45&&!islower(s[_]))||a)?q=x,r=y,main(3,43),p=z,x=X(43),y=Y(43),main(3,s[_]),p+=z,x=X(s[_]),y=Y(s[_]),main(a,_+1),p+=z,x=q,y=r,main(3,94),q=z,x=X(94),y=Y(94),main(3,s[_]),q+=z,x=X(s[_]),y=Y(s[_]),main(!a,_+1),q+=z,z=(q<p?q:p):(main(3,s[_]),q=z,x=X(s[_]),y=Y(s[_]),main(a,_+1),z+=q):(main(3,61)):(a<3?s=((char**)_)[1],x=0,y=1,main(1,0),printf("%d",z):(x=X(_)-x,y=Y(_)-y,x+=10*(x<0),y+=4*(y<0),z=(x>5?10-x:x)+(y>2?4-y:y)));}
```